# dataframe + pandas + select specific rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new in using pandas and one of my functions does not behave as expected. I have this dataframe:

```
     title_year        gross
0          2009  7.60506e+08
1          2007  3.09404e+08
2          2015  2.00074e+08
3          2012  4.48131e+08
5          2012  7.30587e+07
6          2007   3.3653e+08
7          2010  2.00807e+08
8          2015  4.58992e+08
9          2009  3.01957e+08
```

The function is:

```
def analysis_gross_per_year(year1, year2):
    year_df = data[['title_year', 'gross']]
    check = True
    year_df.title_year = year_df.title_year.fillna('Not Given')
    year_df.gross = year_df.gross.fillna('Not Given')
    year_df = year_df[year_df.gross != 'Not Given']
    gross_year = year_df[year_df.title_year.str.contains(year1, na=True)]
    number = int(year1)
    while check :
        if str(number) == year2:
            check = False
        else:
            number = number + 1
            df1 = year_df[year_df.title_year.str.contains(str(number), na=False)]
            gross_year = pd.concat([gross_year, df1])
            print (df1)
```

I give the function 2 parameters year 1 and year 2 and it should display a line graph for average, min, max based on gross earning for the years provided.

E.g if 2013 and 2015. It should display a line graph for 2013, 2014, 2015. However when I run str.contains(year1, na=True) it returns an empty dataframe. Can you tell me why ?

Comment: I am confused as to why you are using all these string methods for numbers. Can you try to piece together a reproducible example including construction of the mini-df?

Comment: because they are in the dataframe as strings not integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided your title_year column is cast to an int, you could do something like the following.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

def range_plot(year1, year2, agg):
    for a in agg: # iterate through aggregate methods
        _ = df[df['title_year'].between(year1, year2)] # subset DataFrame to contain only the year ranges specified
        _ = _.groupby('title_year').agg(a) # groupby title_year, compute summary statistic
        plt.plot(_.index.values, _['gross'], label=a) # plot

    plt.legend() # display legend
    plt.xlabel('Year')
    plt.ylabel('Gross')
    plt.title("{} - {}".format(year1, year2))
```

year1 and year2 are ints, and agg is a list of those aggregate functions you want to plot.

```
range_plot(2009, 2015, ['mean', 'sum', 'min', 'max'])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ben,
Thanks that's what I was looking for. However some of the rows don't have a value and I think that's why I'm not getting a mean. Could you help me on how to address this issue as well ?

Comment: What do you mean by some rows don't have a value? Do you mean there is no value in the gross column for a given year, or that there are rows where both the title_year and gross columns are blank?

Answer (score 0):

I am also a bit confused by the given code snippet, but if you just want to select certain years (as str values) in the dataframe, you could for example create a list of the years and then filter the dataframe accordingly.

```
years_to_select = ['2012', '2013', '2014']
filtered_df = original_df[original_df['year'].isin(years_to_select)]
```

Comment: Hi yeah that's what I'm looking for, but whenever I run the code I get an empty Dataframe. I tried yours as well and I still get empty dataframe